# Can we define relations in Z3?

Tags: z3, relation, smt, sat-solvers

I am new to z3 SMT solver. I need to define a relation, instead of a function. I mean a function that can return more than one value. I looked up the tutorial, and couldn't find anything. I appreciate if you can help me in this regard.

Thanks a lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the logics that supports the **ArrayEx** theory, which provides the **Array** sort and associated functions for manipulating arrays.  You can then have your functions return array values which can contain arbitrarily many Ints or Bools or whatever.

[This SMT tutorial](http://www.grammatech.com/resource/smt/SMTLIBTutorial.pdf) is a good resource that gathers many SMT details into one place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will look into the tutorial. Theoretically, it will work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, SMT "naturally" supports relational programming. You can simply disjunct the possible values for an argument, and thus achieve the desired result. Something like:

```
(declare-fun foo ((Int)) Int)
(assert (or (= (foo 3) 4) (= (foo 3) 5)))
(check-sat)
(eval (foo 3))   ; might produce 4 of 5
(assert (distinct (foo 3) 4))
(check-sat)
(eval (foo 3))   ; will produce 5
(assert (distinct (foo 3) 5))
(check-sat)      ; will declare unsat
```

Here're you're saying `foo` when applied to `3`, can produce `4` or `5`. And then you can assert "further" facts to constrain the space as needed; or leave it free. You can use this trick to essentially model `foo` as a relation; making the SMT-solver to behave as a relational-programming-language..

Of course, how you really want to go about modeling relations really depends on the problem at hand. The above may not be the best choice for your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I see what you mean. But I need a relation that actually returns more than one value in the solution.

Comment: You can query multiple times, after asserting that the previous model is not valid. This is how "all-satisfying-assignments" is typically implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following example is probably what you look for:

```
(define-fun sqrt ((a Int) (b Int)) Bool
    (= (* b b) a)
)
(declare-const a  Int)
(declare-const b1 Int)
(declare-const b2 Int)
(assert (sqrt a b1))
(assert (sqrt a b2))
(assert (not (= b1 b2)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

And when I call z3 I get:

```
$ z3 -smt2 rel.smt
sat
(model 
  (define-fun b2 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun a () Int
    4)
  (define-fun b1 () Int
    (- 2))
)
```

The `sqrt` relation is simply a set of ordered pairs: `{(a,b) | a == b*b}`.
and both `(4,2)` and `(4,-2)` belong to this relation. In SMT phrasing,
this means that both `sqrt(4,2)` and `sqrt(4,-2)` are `true`. This corresponds
to your question's phrasing where `4` can have multiple values.
Unfortunately, other answers like the one that uses `foo` **do not really handle relations** but rather ask the solver **to choose between two functions**.